# How to include Coral into Yocto Build

Tags: yocto, google-coral, yocto-recipe, edge-tpu, pycoral

I am trying to build the pycoral for my yocto board(Renesas RZV2M) but unable to get the suitable recipe and also didn't find libedgetpu recipe, as both will be required for object detection. I am using Google Coral USB Accelerator device.

I had find many recipe but none are supporting for building the pycoral in yocto board

I am expecting a solution so that pycoral must be installed in yocto

Comment: Which release of Yocto Project are you using?
Post here the error you are getting when creating the pycoral recipe.

Comment: I assume you know there is a [meta-coral](https://github.com/mirzak/meta-coral) layer, right? I never used this particular layer myself, but at least it contains a recipe for `libedgetpu`, as you requested.  Can you elaborate on your setup? What does your local.conf look like? What layers are you using?

Comment: @MiEbe thanks for reply.
I already tried to include meta-coral with my BSP layer, but got some version mismatch error during bitbake, As my BSP layer is form dunfell branch and this meta-coral is from any other.

Can someone guide me to modify this meta-coral to include it for dunfell bsp yocto tag.

Comment: hello @CleitonBueno, i am using dunfell branch yocto bsp [yocto BSP layer](https://github.com/renesas-rz/meta-renesas?search=1)

Comment: @PrajwalBhopale I used the following recipes and they worked for a customer: [python3-pycoral_1.0.1.bb](https://github.com/digi-embedded/meta-digi/blob/gatesgarth/meta-digi-dey/recipes-devtools/python3-pycoral/python3-pycoral_1.0.1.bb) [libedgetpu_13.0.bb](https://github.com/digi-embedded/meta-digi/blob/gatesgarth/meta-digi-arm/recipes-bsp/libedgetpu/libedgetpu_13.0.bb)

Comment: I am getting error "ERROR: Layer digi-dey is not compatible with the core layer which only supports these series: hardknott (layer is compatible with kirkstone)" while trying to add python3-pycoral and "ERROR: Layer coral-bsp is not compatible with the core layer which only supports these series: hardknott (layer is compatible with mickledore)" while trying to use meta-coral. Any similar one which hardknott branch?